# Compare two columns with a set of numbers in a file and print matching numbers for every row using unix

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have tried to compare the third and fifth columns in a TSV file which have a set of numbers separated by spaces and would like print match number/s in a new column by bash programming. In fact I created two arrays for these columns in order to compare both of them and print matched numbers and if there are not matches between third and fifth column print "not matches". However the code does not work correctly. I have tried similar scripts but I don't get it. In summary the input is something like:

```
rs935    FUCA    6 29 61 63 67 70 133 134 150 159 166 208 220 260    V    260 135 49 159
rs699    AGT     10 113 117 255 263 288 312 369 381     M   268
rs4230  CFHR1    12 69 85 119 132 141 161 171 173 177 248 252 270 281 291 302 305 309 314   R    302 237
```

and the desired output should be:

```
rs935    FUCA    V:159-260
rs699    AGT     M:not matches
rs4230  CFHR1    R:302
```

...and so on

this is the code:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"}
    {delete a n=split($3,a3," ");
                m=split($5,a5," ");
            for(i=1;i<=m;i++) a[a5[i]];
            SEP="\n"
            for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {if(a3[i] in a)  {both=both SEP a3[i]; SEP="-"}
                    print $1,$2,$4 ":" both }' "input.tsv" > "output.tsv"
```

How can I get it in unix environment? Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't describe your input files in prose.  Write the actual input text in the question.  Not "First column: XXX, Second column: YYY" but "XXX YYY".

Comment: Ok. Are input tabulated files. How do I put the tab into the question to reproduce the actual input?

Comment: Like "copy" then "paste"?

Comment: Example looks wrong. In the first line 260 is not in column 5.

Comment: Ok. I have modified the question in order to understand better. You are right mlambrichs, I have now included 260 in fifth column. Thanks in advance for all.

Comment: Ok. I would like compare third and fifth columns and print matching numbers that appear in both columns. The numbers are separated by spaces. The output conserve first and second  columns in the same way. And finally print a new column that contain the fourth column followed by ':' and the matching numbers that appear in both columns for each row separated by "-". But is not necessary '-'. Could be a space or ",". The meaning of "-" is simply a separator between matching numbers. In fact, the file contains thousand rows but I have only written the two first rows in the output

Comment: You are completely right. Now I Include the third line to the output text and the last explanation. I think your script works correctly. Thanks a lot Ed Morton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very unclear but is this what you're trying to do?

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
{
    delete a3values
    split($3,a3list,/ /)
    for (idx in a3list) {
        a3value = a3list[idx]
        a3values[a3value]
    }

    split($5,a5list,/ /)

    both = "not matches"
    for (idx in a5list) {
        a5value = a5list[idx]
        if (a5value in a3values) {
             both = (both == "not matches" ? "" : both "-") a5value
        }
    }
    print $1, $2, $4 ":" both
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
rs935   FUCA    V:260-159
rs699   AGT     M:not matches
rs4230  CFHR1   R:302
```

Comment: Yes, I think this is the goal. I have commented 5 minutes ago to answer your request. I would like compare third and fifth columns and print matching numbers that appear in both columns. The numbers are separated by spaces. The output conserve first and second columns in the same way. And finally print a new column that contain the fourth column followed by ':' and the matching numbers that appear in both columns for each row separated by "-". But is not necessary '-'. Could be a space or ",". The meaning of "-" is simply a separator between matching numbers.

Comment: Thanks other time. I will see stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers